# No module named swagger_server

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I am trying to launch a flask-generated local server from swagger editor online, in YAML.

Unfortunately, after doing this command

```
pip3install -r requirements.txt
```

that works very fine, I use

```
python -m swagger_server
```

The output is

```
No module named swagger_server
```

Anyone knows how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't placed in the right directory. You must use it in command line in the root directory when you have downloaded the project, usually `python-flask-server-generated`.
Unfortunately, this isn't specified on the installation guide.